# Alfresco create new form in admin-console

Tags: workflow, yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a custom workflow. In my workflow I need to choose type of currency in dropdown. As per my client requirement I need to make a form in admin console which will allow to add, edit and delete and view currency exactly like groups in admin console. These currency need inturn be loaded to dropdown on workflow creation.

Problem for me is not to show form in admin console, I know this should be placed in `org/alfresco/components/console`. But to create a page with crud functionality exactly like groups page.
Where and how to save and retrieve the post data from the form?

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.b and I have gone through all documentation. But could not find help for my requirement.
Please suggest how can i achieve this? I am new to alfresco. I have been using alfresco for 3 weeks only.

Comment: did you found this answer use full?

Answer (score 0):

You can create datalist from site as per your requirement.CRUD will be all ready provided in that datalist.

Than use the data of data list inside workflow form.

For above things you may need to create below things.

1.Custom Content Model Datalist(Fields will be as per your requirement)

2.Alfresco Javascript (For retrieving details in JSON format, from the list which you have created).This will be server side web script in alfresco

3.Create FTL form template which will loaded in form as a combo box.In this file you need to create java script instance for rendering data from web script which we have created in 2nd point

4.Create javascript file for rendering data.

You need to do some Research for above points if you dont know anything.

Comment: did you found this use full?